# Convert MEL to python command

Tags: python, maya, mel, pymel

I am looking for a way to convert this MEL line `mel.eval('cameraMakeNode 2 "";')` into Python.

I can't find anything in the documentation, is used to convert a camera to camera aim.

Comment: How is this not Python already?

Comment: yes but I was looking for a built in python command for it.. since sometimes I get this error ```# Error: RuntimeError: Error occurred during execution of MEL script```

Comment: The "cameraMakeNode" is a mel script. You would to have to write a new script which does the same if you need it for python. The script expects either a camera as argument or that you have a camera selected.

Comment: if you type the mel command : whatis, it will print the path of this mel script

Answer (score 0):

I hope this finds you well. Here is the code that worked for me:

```
import pymel.core as pm
pm.mel.cameraMakeNode(3, "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but doesn't this work?:

```
    import maya.mel
    maya.mel.eval("cameraMakeNode 2 '';")
```

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33735667)